# How to render data returned from an asynchronous hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, react-hooks

The code below is a simplified example of my problem. There is a lot more going on in the actual codebase, so let's just assume that my `useHook` function must be asynchronous and we cannot just fetch the data inside the useEffect hook.

It currently renders `{}`, but I want it to render `"Data to be displayed"`

```
const fetch = async () => {
  /* This code can't be changed */
  return "Data to be displayed"
}

const useFetch = async () => { // This function must be asynchronous
  let data = await fetch();
  return data;
};

const App = () =>  {
  const data = useFetch();
  const [state, setState] = useState(data);
  useEffect(() => {
    setState(data);
  }, [data]);
  return <h1>{JSON.stringify(state)}</h1>
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What is this useHook? You can run an async function in the useEffect hook

Comment: Your useFetch function returns a promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change
`const data = useFetch();` to `const data = await useFetch();`

Answer (score 0):

Move called inside the useEffect like this:

```
const App = () =>  {
 const [state, setState] = useState({});
 useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
        const data = await useFetch();
        setState(data);
    }
    fetchData()
 }, []);  // [] load first time
 return <h1>{JSON.stringify(state)}</h1>
}
```

Comment: I cannot use `useFetch` inside the `useEffect` hook though. Hooks are supposed to be called in the top level in react components unconditionally.

Comment: but i remove the condition in useEffect, this run once